# Using @EJB injection in an Application Client, both in same EAR

Tags: eclipse, dependency-injection, glassfish, ejb, application-client

I've searched now for days to find some solution for my, in my opinion not too hard but obviously unsolvable problem.

I have an EAR project containing Some EJB, a web client (works fine) and now I added an Application Client Module.

As everything is in the same project, I thought a simple @EJB injection in the main class of the application client would do. I also tried a JNDI lookup.
I use eclipse and glassfish as a server and tried to run the application 1. in eclipse (there my injected bean is just null) and 2. downloaded the client-stub from the glassfish administration and tried to start it with sh appclient -client (or -jar) OmazanClient.jar (and also the other two jars hidden in the client-stub folder). There I get mostly a "ClassNotFoundExeption:Main" like

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.ACCClassLoader.findClass(ACCClassLoader.java:212)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.FacadeLaunchable.getMainClass(FacadeLaunchable.java:262)
at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.setClient(AppClientContainer.java:324)
at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainerBuilder.createContainer(AppClientContainerBuilder.java:185)
at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainerBuilder.newContainer(AppClientContainerBuilder.java:172)
at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.createContainerForAppClientArchiveOrDir(AppClientFacade.java:492)
at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.createContainer(AppClientFacade.java:454)
at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.prepareACC(AppClientFacade.java:269)
at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.agent.AppClientContainerAgent.premain(AppClientContainerAgent.java:82)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:323)
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:338)
```

So for the injection, my code looks like:

```
public class Main {
@EJB (mappedName="ejb/customerBean")
public static CustomerInterface customerBean;
@EJB (mappedName="ejb/productBean")
public static ProductInterface productBean;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        Main m = new Main();
        m.runDialog();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/* (non-Java-doc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#Object()
 */
public Main() {
    super();

}
private void runDialog() throws Exception{
    System.out.println("Test");
    List<ProductDTO> productList = productBean.getAllProducts();

...
```

My remote interface looks like this:

```
@Remote
public interface ProductInterface {

public int addProduct(String productName);
public void deleteProduct(int prodid);
public void updateProduct(int prodid, String newName);
List<ProductDTO> getAllProducts();
```

...

My implementation is this:

```
/**
 * Session Bean implementation productInterface
 *  */
@Stateless(mappedName="ejb/productBean")
@LocalBean
@WebService
public class ProductBean implements ProductInterface {

@EJB ProductEAO eao;
@EJB Conversion conv;

/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public ProductBean() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public int addProduct(String prodName) {
    return eao.addProduct(prodName);
}

@Override
public List<ProductDTO> getAllProducts() {

         List<ProductDTO> result = new ArrayList<ProductDTO>();
         List<Product> allProducts = eao.allProducts();
            for (Product pr : allProducts) {
               ProductDTO ci = conv.fromProduct(pr);
                result.add(ci);
            }
            return result;

}
```

... and so on (all methods required by the interface are implemented, just try to keep it shorter here)

and the MANIFEST.MF is just

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Main
```

I've tried a lot like JNDI lookup, giving the bean names (see example) etc. But either the interface is not found (lookup) or the bean simply null.

How ever I am also not quite sure how to run the application client. I thought glassfishs appclient is the right starting point? It shall be a console-interaction so no swing components or anything similar.

Now I'd be thankful for any suggestions what I might have missed.

Cheers :)

---

Found a solution. Somehow, JNDI works now. Another problem was that my db query returned an Object and not primitive value or string - this caused a buffer error.

However, I am still confused on how to export an run an application client correctly. Maybe someone has an idea?!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25985288/262852 for an example of JNDI lookup for a remote EJB deployed to Glassfish from an EAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good example here: [Create and Run a JEE6 Client Application with Netbeans 6.8 and Glassfish V3 - Part 2: Enhancing and Deploying the Application](http://log4ray.blogspot.com/2010/02/create-and-run-jee6-client-application_17.html). It is a few years old, but it does give a pretty good overview.