# Portable JNDI Syntax lookup for EJB on Glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, jndi

[Previous attempts were to have Netbeans deploy an EJB module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970170/illegalargumentexception-invalid-ejb-jar-helloejb-it-contains-zero-ejb), which builds as a JAR rather than an EAR, onto the Glassfish server which Netbeans has access to.  However,  deploying that JAR to Glassfish through the CLI with `asadmin` [possibly runs into a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25972994/262852).

The EAR deploys through the CLI without issue -- however, the JNDI names for the EJB doesn't appear to work.  What is the discrepancy?

> 32.4.1.1 Portable JNDI Syntax
>
> Three JNDI namespaces are used for portable JNDI lookups: java:global,
>   java:module, and java:app.
>
> The java:global JNDI namespace is the portable way of finding remote
>   enterprise beans using JNDI lookups. JNDI addresses are of the
>   following form: java:global[/application name]/module name /enterprise
>   bean name[/interface name ] Application name and module name default
>   to the name of the application and module minus the file extension.
>   Application names are required only if the application is packaged
>   within an EAR. The interface name is required only if the enterprise
>   bean implements more than one business interface.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/ejb-intro004.htm

What is the correct syntax to lookup this bean?  Is it `java:global/HelloEAR/HelloEAR-ejb/greetings.GreetingsBeanRemote`?  I've tried more than a few variants of that without success.

deploying the app:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin/asadmin list-applications
HelloEAR  <ear, ejb>  
Command list-applications executed successfully.
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin/asadmin undeploy HelloEAR
Command undeploy executed successfully.
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin/asadmin list-applications
Nothing to list.
No applications are deployed to this target server.
Command list-applications executed successfully.
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin/asadmin deploy NetBeansProjects/HelloEAR/dist/HelloEAR.ear 
Application deployed with name HelloEAR.
Command deploy executed successfully.
thufir@dur:~$
```

the server.log:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ tail glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log -n 15
[2014-09-22T04:58:42.666-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-EJB-00055] [javax.enterprise.ejb.container] [tid: _ThreadID=650 _ThreadName=admin-listener(9)] [timeMillis: 1411387122666] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB GreetingsBean: [greetings.GreetingsBeanRemote#greetings.GreetingsBeanRemote, greetings.GreetingsBeanRemote]]]

[2014-09-22T04:58:43.619-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=650 _ThreadName=admin-listener(9)] [timeMillis: 1411387123619] [levelValue: 900] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2014-09-22T04:58:43.628-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=650 _ThreadName=admin-listener(9)] [timeMillis: 1411387123628] [levelValue: 900] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2014-09-22T04:58:43.634-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=650 _ThreadName=admin-listener(9)] [timeMillis: 1411387123634] [levelValue: 900] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2014-09-22T04:58:44.757-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=650 _ThreadName=admin-listener(9)] [timeMillis: 1411387124757] [levelValue: 800] [[
  HelloEAR was successfully deployed in 2,312 milliseconds.]]

thufir@dur:~$
```

attempting the lookup:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin/appclient -client NetBeansProjects/RemoteJNDI/dist/RemoteJNDI.jar 
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for '[greetings.GreetingsBeanRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3700, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS=pass123, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=localhost, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL=user1} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [greetings.GreetingsBeanRemote not found]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at net.bounceme.dur.jndi.RemoteJNDI.main(RemoteJNDI.java:15)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [greetings.GreetingsBeanRemote not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:237)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:204)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:66)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.RemoteSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(RemoteSerialContextProviderImpl.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie.dispatchToMethod(ReflectiveTie.java:143)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:173)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1549)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(MessageMediatorImpl.java:930)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:213)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:694)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.doWork(MessageMediatorImpl.java:2222)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
thufir@dur:~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why** is the invocation of the bean without "java:" or anything like that?

success:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin/asadmin list-applications
Nothing to list.
No applications are deployed to this target server.
Command list-applications executed successfully.
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin/asadmin deploy NetBeansProjects/HelloEAR/dist/HelloEAR.ear 
Application deployed with name HelloEAR.
Command deploy executed successfully.
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin/asadmin list-applications
HelloEAR  <ear, ejb>  
Command list-applications executed successfully.
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin/appclient -client NetBeansProjects/RemoteJNDI/dist/RemoteJNDI.jar 
hello world
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$
```

client code:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.jndi;

import greetings.GreetingsBeanRemote;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class RemoteJNDI {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RemoteJNDI.class.getName());

    public static void main(String... args) {
        try {
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
//            Object obj = ctx.lookup("java:global/HelloEAR/HelloEAR-ejb/greetings.GreetingsBeanRemote");
            Object obj = ctx.lookup("greetings.GreetingsBeanRemote");
            GreetingsBeanRemote gbr = (GreetingsBeanRemote) obj;
            System.out.println(gbr.hi());
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

ejb:

```
package greetings;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class GreetingsBean implements GreetingsBeanRemote {

    @Override
    public String hi() {
        return "hello world";
    }

    @Override
    public String bye() {
        return "bye";
    }

}
```

interface:

```
package greetings;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface GreetingsBeanRemote {

    public String hi();

    public String bye();
}
```

server log:

```
[2014-09-22T17:55:56.091-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1411433756091] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2014-09-22T17:55:56.233-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-EJB-00054] [javax.enterprise.ejb.container] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1411433756233] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Portable JNDI names for EJB GreetingsBean: [java:global/HelloEAR/HelloEAR-ejb/GreetingsBean!greetings.GreetingsBeanRemote, java:global/HelloEAR/HelloEAR-ejb/GreetingsBean]]]

[2014-09-22T17:55:56.235-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-EJB-00055] [javax.enterprise.ejb.container] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1411433756235] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB GreetingsBean: [greetings.GreetingsBeanRemote#greetings.GreetingsBeanRemote, greetings.GreetingsBeanRemote]]]

[2014-09-22T17:55:56.321-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1411433756321] [levelValue: 900] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2014-09-22T17:55:56.341-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1411433756341] [levelValue: 900] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2014-09-22T17:55:56.349-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1411433756349] [levelValue: 900] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2014-09-22T17:55:56.819-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1411433756819] [levelValue: 800] [[
  HelloEAR was successfully deployed in 842 milliseconds.]]

thufir@dur:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven as well then check if "-1.0-SNAPSHOT" (or other version/as per your app) is attached at the end of the application-ejb file name as "application-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT", The full name would be "java:global/application-ear/application-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/fileName"